# IPython %%python magic command

Tags: command, jupyter-notebook, ipython

I have discovered the magic command `%%python` thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48135559/173003), where it prevents a crash of the IPython's kernel after a Tkinter window is closed.

According to the [documentation](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html):

> `%%python`
>   %%python script magic
>   Run cells with python in a subprocess.

Has this magic command any other use?

Comment: This command runs a script in a subshell - you use it anytime you want to execute a Python script. Is something in the description unclear?

Comment: A Python script is already directly executable as a code cell in Jupyter with a Python kernel (no need to add `%%python`). I add the tag `Jupyter` in case this makes my question clearer.

Comment: I know, by subshell I meant a different process is spawned to run the child. I should have emphasized you want to execute the script in a different process - (such as protecting the original process from segmentation faults). This would be necessary to make IPython behave like a "regular" shell. Are there any particular use-cases you are interested in?

Comment: Thanks. No, in fact I can't imagine a concrete use case, apart from the one I have discovered in the linked answer. I thought initially that this command would prevent the kernel's lock during the execution of a long-running cell, but the behavior seems identical.

Comment: I really think it's just to allow IPython to act as a full fledged terminal. That's why it provides the other magic `%script` commands (`%sh`).

Comment: The rest of the docs say it's a shortcut for `%%script python`.  Which in turn `is like the #! line of script`.